# From DataFrame to int, with single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1. I'm trying to convert a csv file that is in pandas data frame type, into an integer.
2. I already tried pandas astype way
3. Any second look or advice is well received

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

col_list = ["Solicitud"]
    daf = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\N\inapi_scraper\solicitudes_v0.csv", usecols=[0], names=['Solicitud'], header=None)#, usecols=col_list)
    datf=daf[0:737]
    df[datf] = df[datf].astype(dtype=int)
```

I always receive this error:

`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 1):

`datf` is already a dataframe and not a mask (and `df` does not exist?)

```
datf = daf.loc[0:737].astype(int)
```

Use `.iloc` or `loc` depends on your index.

Comment: I tried with .iloc and .loc and still get from print(type(datf)) the class
'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,' so I think it's not working